# JSONDecodeError: Unexpected UTF-8 BOM: Display problems in bash?

Tags: python, json, bash, utf-8

I want to analyse the text in a .jsonl document (using Python 3). The code I'm running works fine as long as the text is in English, yet for arabic text files I receive the Error message: 
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Unexpected UTF-8 BOM (decode using utf-8-sig): line 1 column 1 (char 0)

I read through some threads and figured I might need to decode it which I did adding .decode(utf-8-sig) to json.loads (see code). Doing so, resulted in the following Error message: 
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'

I also changed the LANG settings to utf8 in ~/.bashrc in case it has sth to do with the bash terminal not being able to display the characters properly but same errors.

Here the code and thanks in advance!

```
import sys 
from collections import Counter 
import json

def get_hashtags(tweet): 
  entities = tweet.get('entities', {}) 
  hashtags = entities.get('hashtags', []) 
  return [tag['text'].lower() for tag in hashtags] 


if __name__ == '__main__': 
  fname = sys.argv[1]
  with open(fname, 'r') as f: 
    hashtags = Counter() 
    for line in f: 
      tweet = json.loads(line.decode('utf-8-sig'))
      hashtags_in_tweet = get_hashtags(tweet) 
      hashtags.update(hashtags_in_tweet) 
    for tag, count in hashtags.most_common(20): 
      print("{}: {}".format(tag, count))
```

Comment: You are trying to decode a string. "line" is a string in a file. Why not just json.loads(open(fname).read().decode('utf-8-sig'))?

Comment: Hi, added the line and received following error: File "frequent_hashtags.py", line 20, in <module>
    tweet = json.loads(open(fname).read().decode('utf-8-sig'))
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'

Comment: My bad, i missed the .jsonl notation and thought your whole file was a json. Just provide the encoding when you open the file then, open in Python 3 should already support that. Too late as it was already answered below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`io.open`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html#io.open) which supports decoding on fly (via `encoding` parameter), in both Python 2 and Python 3 (actually, in Python 3, `io.open` is the default `open`):

```
import io

with io.open(fname, 'r', encoding='utf-8-sig') as f: 
    # ...
    for line in f: 
        tweet = json.loads(line)
        # ...
```